# What are the probabilities of drawing cards with Niv-Mizzet reborn in Magic: the Gathering

Tags: combinatorics

Niv-Mizzet Reborn is a card from a recent Magic: the Gathering set.

The card says:

> When Niv-Mizzet Reborn enters the battlefield, reveal the top ten cards of your library. For each color pair, choose a card that’s exactly those colors from among them. Put the chosen cards into your hand and the rest on the bottom of your library in a random order.

The colour pairs mentioned are part of the cost of each card. Each card costs are made up of up to 5 different symbols (W, U, B, R, G). E.g. a card that costs WUB has 3 different colour pairs.

What I want to know is, from a deck of 60 cards, what are the probabilities of the top ten being up to 10 different pairs (e.g. the probabilities of 1 unique pair, 2 unique pairs etc) assuming you have 5 lots of each pair in the deck (e.g. 5×WU, 5×WB ...etc.) and 4 other cards (you need to have used 6 cards to play Niv-Mizzet reborn).

I've already tried to use www.deckulator.appspot.com to work or the probabilities of the perfect 10-pair draw.

[image: calculation of multivariate hypergeometric probabilities]

But it looks like it's not as simple as just multiplying by the number of ways of drawing a [combination of pairs](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(10+choose+5)%2B(10+choose+6)%2B(10+choose+7)%2B(10+choose+8)%2B(10+choose+9)+%2B1) (e.g. 10 choose 5 + 10 choose 6 etc). As those seems like too good a set of odds.

Comment: So to be clear: you're assuming 50 cards in the library evenly distributed between 10 classes and you want to count the number of ways of getting 1, 2, 3, ..., 10 distinct classes in the first ten cards?

Comment: @PeterTaylor that sounds about right